# Find value of $\sec80^\circ-2\cos20^\circ-\dfrac{4}{\sec20^\circ}+\dfrac{1}{2\sin10^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt :
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\cos80^\circ}-2\cos20^\circ-4\cos20^\circ+\dfrac{1}{\sin10^\circ}\\
\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin10^\circ}+\dfrac{1}{2\sin10^\circ}\right)-6\cos20^\circ\\
\dfrac{3}{2\sin10^\circ}-6\cos20^\circ
\end{align*}
This seem like the value wouldn't be an integer, but after typing in WolframAlpha it returned 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Werner Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html),  $2\sin B\cos A=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$

$$\dfrac{3(1-4\sin10^\circ\cos20^\circ)}{2\sin10^\circ}$$

$$=\dfrac{3(1-2(\sin(20+10)^\circ-\sin(20-10)^\circ))}{2\sin10^\circ}$$

$$=?$$

**Generalization**:

$$\dfrac1{2\sin x}-2\cos y=\dfrac{1-2(\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y))}{2\sin x}$$

We need $\sin(x+y)=\dfrac12$

and $\sin(x-y)=\pm\sin x\iff0=\sin^2x-\sin^2(x-y)=\sin(2x-y)\sin y$

Either $\sin y=0\implies \sin(x+180^\circ n)=\dfrac12, x=?$

Or $\sin(2x-y)=0\implies y=2x+m180^\circ\implies\dfrac12=\sin(3x+m180^\circ), x=?$

where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers

Here $x=10^\circ, m=0$